# how to read from a text file contents file name extension in c++?

Tags: c++, file, text-files

Hello I want to read from a text file full of directory contents

Here's my example:

below is my text file called MyText.txt

MyText.txt

```
title.txt,image.png,sound.mp3
```

I want to be able to read that .txt extension not the filename and I want it to be for file extensions only for example .txt or .mp3 how would I do that in c++?.

When I mean read I mean reference it in a if statement like this:

```
if(.mp3 exists in a text file)
{
  fprintf(stderr,"sees the mp3 extensions");
}
```

I'm running Windows 7 32-bit.

I need a more cross platform approach.

Comment: It's not about the language, it's about the operating system, which you haven't mentioned.

Comment: Can you please add some punctuation to make your question more clear? I don't understand "i want it to be specific too file extensions only for example ..."

Answer (score 2):

May I suggest you to read a tutorial on C++ file handling and another one on C++ strings?

There is no a quick solution: you have to read the file using the [**ifstream**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream/) class.
After reading the file and storing it in one or more [**strings**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/), you can then use the *find* and *substr* string methods to create a [**queue**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/queue/) of discrete filenames. Using the same methods, you can then split the queued elements again, in order to find the extensions and add them to a [**set**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/set/). A set does not allow duplicates, so you are sure all the extensions will appear only once.